# How to avoid post_max_size

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

I have a problem. I am creating my own PHP application and I want to allow users to upload files.

**My PHP**

```
function make_upload() {
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($_FILES);
 echo "</pre>";
}

if (isset($_GET["upload"]) && $_GET["upload"] == "1") {
 make_upload();
}
```

**My HTML**

```
<form action="?upload=1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input name="file[]" type="file" multiple/>
 <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

When I try to browse and select many files, the `print_r($_FILES);` shows blank `Array ( )` instead of the array with my files. That's happens because of `post_max_size` which is set to `8M`. If I change my `post_max_size` then I can select more images.

I want to share my application to be installed on websites, but I don't want to tell users to increase their `post_max_size`.

Is there any option to avoid `post_max_size`? (I see that in wordpress I can select images which are over the `post_max_size` - how is made?)

Answer (score 2):

you can do it via .htaccess file.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
```

but sometime hosting provider does not allow you to overrite it.  you will get 500 Internal Server Error in that case

Comment: Thank you but I want it to work 100% as WordPress upload works on any configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini :

Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.

```
upload_max_filesize = 40M;
```

Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize

```
post_max_size = 40M;
```

After modifying php.ini file(s), you need to restart your HTTP server to use new configuration.

If you can't change your php.ini, you're out of luck. You cannot change these values at run-time; uploads of file larger than the value specified in php.ini will have failed by the time execution reaches your call to ini_set.

See the [Description of core php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) directives.

Comment: My post says: How to AVOID setting the `post_max_size`.

Comment: @MMPP I got your post but you can not upload files using php larger than limit avoiding its settings.
If you find something please let me know also.

Answer (score 1):

you have not passed array to function pass it when you calling

```
if (isset($_GET["upload"]) && $_GET["upload"] == "1") {
 make_upload($_FILES); // pass this $_FILES array to function
}
```

AND function would be like this

```
function make_upload($_FILES) {
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($_FILES); // will print array
 echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: My code works as expected. I want to AVOID setting the `post_max_size`